# How do you spawn a skeleton without a bow and a name

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was making the Judgement Hall from Undertale (IN MINECRAFT). I already made the music and the map, but what's the command for a skeleton without a bow that has a name?

Comment: You say your making something FROM undertale, which makes it sound like your making it in another game. If that is the case, make sure you change your tag to the game you are actually playing, at least.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that hard.

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~
```

This summons a skeleton on the command block.

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Bob"}
```

This summons a named skeleton. Optionally, you can use the "CustomNameVisible:" tag, to make the name visible even when you don't hover over the skeleton.

```
/summon Skeleton ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Bob",CustomNameVisible:1,HandItems:[{id:"air"},{id:air}]}
```

This last command replaces items in both hands with air (nothing) or in other words, clears them.

Comment: Just as a note: "air" is not a valid inventory item and is thus ignored. The hands will be empty because the `HandItems` list tag was declared, overwriting everything that was previously in the list.

Answer (score -2):

Look at this: http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command-1.9, you can create custom mobs for 1.9 (including the name and nothing in his hand)

Comment: while the link might answer the question, it doesnt help us if it breaks, in the future.  You should provide all relevant information here.e